# How to convert an object to Actual JSX Component inside a Text Tag?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a translation function and facing this issue.

```
<Text style={styles.descText}>
    {`All reports size is
    ${<Text style={styles.downloadSize}>
    {bytesToSize(this.props.downloadSize)} 
    </Text>}
    Text to display
    `}
</Text>
```

You can see there's a Text tag inside a text. but on the screen, it render [Object] instead of a View.Is there anyway to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do `Text` inside `Text`. It should looks like this:

```js
<>
  <Text style={styles.descText}>All reports size is</Text>
  <Text style={styles.downloadSize}>
    {`${bytesToSize(this.props.downloadSize)}`}
  </Text>
  <Text style={styles.descText}>Text to display</Text>
</>
```

Comment: The text tag inside the text is because that bytesToSize() need to have different style. (Bold to be specific)

Comment: ok, I'll edit my answer